# System emails are blocked using sSMTP

Tags: email, ssmtp

I have a home server with a dynamic IP (running Ubuntu 20.04.3) and want to receive the system mails to root as an email. I have set up sSMTP to send email via a Gmail account. Sending emails manually works. Automatically triggered emails caused by system events do not arrive. So I wonder about the difference between sending emails manually and the automatic email events caused by system events.

Here is my sSMTP configuration.

```
$ cat /etc/sSMTP/sSMTP.conf
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=mymail@web.de

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=myhostname

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
FromLineOverride=YES

# Use SSL/TLS before starting negotiation
TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes

AuthUser=gmailuser@gmail.com
AuthPass=gmailpass
```

Sending emails works in principle. I receive emails correctly for all the following commands.

```
$ echo "Content" | mail -s "Subject" mymail@web.de
$ echo "Content" | mailx -s "Subject" mymail@web.de
$ echo -e "Subject: Subject\n\nContent" | ssmtp mymail@web.de
```

However, if I trigger an automatic mail to root, things are different. For example, I intentionally give a wrong password for a sudo command.

```
$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for myuser: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for myuser: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

This issue triggers an email to mymail@web.de, but the email does not arrive. Instead, I get an email to gmailuser@gmail.com with the following error message.

> 554 Transaction failed Reject due to policy restrictions. For explanation visit https://web.de/email/senderguidelines?ip=209.85.221.44&c=hi

Here is the header:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns; gmailuser@gmail.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 13:14:10 -0700 (PDT)
X-Original-Message-ID: <ID@mx.google.com>

Final-Recipient: rfc822; mymail@web.de
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx-ha02.web.de. (212.227.17.8, the server for the domain web.de.)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554-Transaction failed
 554-Reject due to policy restrictions.
 554 For explanation visit https://web.de/email/senderguidelines?ip=209.85.221.44&c=hi
Last-Attempt-Date: Wed, 25 Aug 2021 13:14:10 -0700 (PDT)
```

How can I find out the underlying command used by the automatic email events? And how can I change the automated email events to behave like the manual ones such that I receive the emails at mymail@web.de? Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does it show up as sent in your gmail account? Any differences?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Both kinds of emails (the ones that are delivered and those that are not) show up as sent. There are slight differences in the header for these emails. Maybe this is the reason for the problem? Why are there differences in the header? https://gist.github.com/fzalkow/7a494935feafe2e84ecaa1fa69bc70c8

Comment: Did you read the link the web.de server returned to you? One of the bullet points is that the To header must be correct. Your failed emails have `To: root` instead of `To: mymail@web.de`

Comment: The "To"-field might be the reason for the problem. But how can I get it to have the correct "To" field? I already set up an alias from root to mymail@web.de in `/etc/mail.rc`. This alias works because sending to root via the following command correctly delivers the mail to mymail@web.de. `echo -e "Subject: Subject\n\nContent" | ssmtp root`.

Comment: I just want to give you a minor update. I did not manage to get it working with sSMTP. Instead, I now switched to postfix (using an smtp relay host). Now I receive the mails for root to mymail@web.de, just as I want it to be.